# Bug with writing to file in linux /sys/class/gpio

Tags: c++, linux, file, c++11, sudo

I'm having the strangest bug I've ever seen with a linux system right now and there seem to be only two possible explanations for it -

- Either appending sudo makes file writes instant
- Or appending sudo produces a short delay in executing statements
- Or I've got no clue what's happening with my program

---

Well let me give you some background. I'm currently writing a c++ program for raspberry pi gpio manipulation. There are no visible error in the program as far as I know & since it works with sudo successfully and with delays successfully too. So here's how rpi's gpio work -

> - First you've to export one, to reserve it for manipulation, it will create a new directory as `gpio+number` with several files in it.
>
>   `echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export`
> - Then set it's direction(in means read and out means write)
>
>   `echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction`
> - Then write the value (0 or 1 for off and on)
>
>   `echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value`
> - At the end, unexport it back, the directory will get deleted.
>
>   `echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport`

It doesn't matter whether you do this through bash commands or through c/c++ or any other language IO, since in unix these are just files and you just need to read/write to them. Everything works fine till now. I've tested this manually and it works, so my manual test passes.

---

Now I've a simple test written for my program which looks like this -

```
TEST(LEDWrites, LedDevice)
{
    Led led1(17, "MyLED");
    // auto b = sleep(1);
    EXPECT_EQ(true, led1.on());
}
```

The Led class `constructor` does the export part - `echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export`, while the `.on()` call sets the direction - `echo "write" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction` and outputs the value as well - `echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value`. Forget about unexport here since it is handled by destructor and plays no role here.

If you're curious, these functions handle I/O like this -

```
{
    const std::string direction = _dir ? "out" : "in";

    const std::string path = GPIO_PATH + "/gpio" + std::to_string(powerPin) + "/direction";

    std::ofstream dirStream(path.c_str(), std::ofstream::trunc);
    if (dirStream) {
        dirStream << direction;
    } else {
        // LOG error here
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

means basic c++ file/io. Now let me explain the bug.

---

First, here are 3 runs of same test -

**`Normal run`** **FAILS**

```
[isaac@alarmpi build]$ ./test/testexe
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 2 tests from 2 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from LEDConstruction
[ RUN      ] LEDConstruction.LedDevice
[       OK ] LEDConstruction.LedDevice (1 ms)
[----------] 1 test from LEDConstruction (1 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from LEDWrites
[ RUN      ] LEDWrites.LedDevice
../test/test.cpp:20: Failure
Value of: led1.on()
  Actual: false
Expected: true
[  FAILED  ] LEDWrites.LedDevice (2 ms)
[----------] 1 test from LEDWrites (3 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 2 test cases ran. (6 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] LEDWrites.LedDevice

 1 FAILED TEST
```

**`run with sudo`** **PASSES**

```
[isaac@alarmpi build]$ sudo ./test/testexe
[sudo] password for isaac: 
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 2 tests from 2 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from LEDConstruction
[ RUN      ] LEDConstruction.LedDevice
[       OK ] LEDConstruction.LedDevice (1 ms)
[----------] 1 test from LEDConstruction (2 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from LEDWrites
[ RUN      ] LEDWrites.LedDevice
[       OK ] LEDWrites.LedDevice (2 ms)
[----------] 1 test from LEDWrites (2 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 2 test cases ran. (5 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```

**`wtf delay run`**  **PASSES**  has uncommented `// auto b = sleep(1);`

```
[isaac@alarmpi build]$ ./test/testexe
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 2 tests from 2 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from LEDConstruction
[ RUN      ] LEDConstruction.LedDevice
[       OK ] LEDConstruction.LedDevice (1 ms)
[----------] 1 test from LEDConstruction (2 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from LEDWrites
[ RUN      ] LEDWrites.LedDevice
[       OK ] LEDWrites.LedDevice (1001 ms)
[----------] 1 test from LEDWrites (1003 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 2 test cases ran. (1005 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```

The only difference b/w delay and normal run is of single uncommented line - `// auto b = sleep(1);` Everything is same including device, directory structure, build conf and everything. **The only things that explains this is linux might be creating that file and its friends sometimes later or it takes some time? and I call `.on()` before that.** Well that could explain it...

**But then why does sudo invocation with no delay passes? Does it makes those writes faster/instant or does it puts the delay statement by itself?** Is this the cause of some kind of buffering? Please say no :/

If it matters, I'm using following dev rule for getting non-sudo access to gpio directory -

```
SUBSYSTEM=="bcm2835-gpiomem", KERNEL=="gpiomem", GROUP="gpio", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpiochip*", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown root:gpio /sys/class/gpio/export /sys/class/gpio/unexport ; chmod 220 /sys/class/gpio/export /sys/class/gpio/unexport'"
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpio*", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown root:gpio /sys%p/active_low /sys%p/direction /sys%p/edge /sys%p/value ; chmod 660 /sys%p/active_low /sys%p/direction /sys%p/edge /sys%p/value'"
```

**EDIT** - As @charles mentioned, I used `std::flush` after every write I made on I/O operations. Still failing.

---

**Strace to the rescue**

---

Let's see the execution of the failing build command -

```
open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
```

`..., 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)`

Okaaay, here's something, that explains why it is passing with sudo. But why is it passing with delay? Let's check that too,

```
open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 4
open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
```

No wait, wtf? This means the permission denied must be for if files aren't created at that time. But how does using `sudo` solves that?

Here's relevant output for sudo -

```
open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 4
open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
```

Comment: how did you even make it work without sudo? Those files require sudo permissions to write I guess?

Comment: use `gpio` group supplied with raspbian or create udev rules copying from it for your distro.

Comment: Streams are buffered by default in C++, aren't they?

Comment: @CharlesAddis they are written when file handles are closed by end of the function calling it's destructors. And what about `sudo` run then?

Comment: You should flush the stream, and see if that helps.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/flush-free/

Comment: your tests are Google Test Framework ?

Comment: @M.M yes I'm using Google Test Framework. Any connection with that?

Comment: If I've got this straight, the problem is that you write to file to change LED state, and you then read from file to check the state, but it appears to be taking a small amount of time for the written state to be readable back?  If so, that sort of thing is entirely normal

Comment: @M.M I don't even wait to read back from file, I write value to it and assume it has been written because file has been `close()`d by function's ending. Does linux perform some form of buffering too?

Comment: Well you're not actually writing a disk file, you are communicating with some hardware device , using the OS's file interface as the communication medium. The device itself might not report that the state has changed until it actually changes, which could take some time after receiving the command.

Comment: @M.M I prepared for that too. There's no device attached at the moment with those gpios.

Comment: You're still communicating with something or other, and that may exhibit delays

Comment: @M.M I had a led at the beginning, but I removed it since I thought it might be the reason for delays. At the moment there is nothing attached to gpio I'm testing, so everything is instant. Ofcourse I'm not reading from it, I'm only writing.

Comment: @CharlesAddis no effect on using `std::flush` either.

Comment: `led1.on()` must do a read of some sort

Comment: @M.M `led.on` just writes `out` to direction and `1` to value. It's quite confusing since it returns a boolean, but that's intentional. It's not a method like `isOn()`. It's more like `turnOn()`

Comment: So what does the return value of `led1.on()` mean and how is it generated? This seems like an important detail to your question but you have said nothing about it.

Comment: @M.M `led.on()` returns false if it's unable to open any of the file mentioned above.

Comment: So your real problem is that opening a file fails? And we got all through your long post and all these comments without you mentioning that until now?

Comment: @M.M opening a file for writing fails, right. But it dosen't fails when I intentionally delay it for 1 second. That means files are not there on the normal run. But what happens with sudo and no delay? That's my question..

Comment: The most likely reason is that there is a timing issue, and whatever changes you make happen to change the timing fractionally.  You should investigate why exactly it fails to open the file and work on fixing that so there is no timing issue.

Comment: @M.M I've updated the question with strace outputs. Would you mind taking a second look?

Comment: When you execute something as root (sudo), linux doesn't perform any permissions check (it just skips them; and for this reason root can do anything). When executing it as a normal user (with group permissions), the time to check permissions can be the discriminant fact. Just an idea.

Comment: @Peregring-lk that way normal run should be slower and should not fail the tests while sudo run should do it beacause files aren't created till then.

Comment: "At the moment there is nothing attached to gpio I'm testing, so everything is instant." Wrong, the actual hardware has to increase the voltage on that pin. The time for the hardware to set the output value is independent of the devices that are attached to the pins.

Comment: My guess would be: When exporting the GPIO, i.e. creating the `gpio17` directory, all nodes are created with default access rights. After a small delay, udev notices the new node and applies the rule, granting write access to group `gpio`. So root can write immediatly, other users only after udev has applied the rule.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a race between udev and your program. When you write to `/sys/class/gpio/export`, the write will not return until the GPIO is fully created. However, once it has been created, you have two processes that simultaneously take action on the new device:

- A hotplug/uevent triggers udev to evaluate its rules. As part of these rules, it will change the ownership and permissions of `/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value`.
- Your program continues. It will immediately try to open `/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value`.

So there is some chance that your program will open the `value` file *before* udev has changed its ownership and permissions. This is in fact very likely, because your udev handler does an execve of a shell which then execve's chown and chmod. But even without that, the scheduler will normally give priority to the task that was already running when returning from a syscall, so your program will usually open the `value` file before udev has even woken up.

By inserting a sleep, you allow udev to do its thing. So to make it robust, you could poll the file with access() before opening it.

It would also help by giving udev higher priority. E.g. `chrt -f -p $(pidof systemd-udevd) 3`. This gives udev real-time priority, which means it will always run before your program. It can also make your system unresponsive so take care.

Answer (score 0):

From your `strace` output

```
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

You are *first* writing `value`, *then* `direction`.
Of course, you should first set the proper direction before writing the value.

Also, you should probably end your output

```
if (dirStream) {
    dirStream << direction;
} else {
    // LOG error here
    return false;
}
```

with a newline.
The `echo` command also appends a newline.

```
if (dirStream) {
    dirStream << direction << std::endl;
} else {
    // LOG error here
    return false;
}
```

(In this case, I would explicitly use `std::endl` to flush. Of course just adding `'\n'` works as well, but making the flush explicit makes the code more robust. As it is, you are now relying on the fact that the stream gets closed immediately after writing—which it might not if you later decide to keep the stream open until the end of your program.)

The missing trailing newline might explain why it works with a delay: after that delay, the driver might interpret the data *as if* there was a newline and assumes no more letters are waiting in the stream.

Comment: Closing the stream also flushes it (which will happen on function return)

Comment: I just said that flushing it explicitly makes the code more robust. Maybe later he decides he wants to leave a stream open (probably rather `value` than `direction`), so he can write multiple values over time. In this case the explicit flush is necessary nonetheless.